# Accessing index of the top num.out outliers in baysout function from the 'dprep' R package

Tags: r

I am using the baysout function for outlier detection from the 'dprep' package in R. The returned value is supposed to be a 2 column matrix according to the R documentation. The first column contains the indexes of the top num.out (user defined number of outliers to return) and the second, the outlyingness measure for each index.

The problem is that I want to access the index number separately but I am not able to do this. The function is actually returning an num.out x 1 matrix as opposed to a num.out x 2 matrix. The index value and the outlyingness measure are there but I cannot access them separately. Please see sample code below:

```
#  Install and load the dprep library
install.packages("dprep")
library(dprep)

# Create 5x3 matrix for input to baysout function
A = matrix(c(0.8, 0.4, 1.2, 0.4, 1.2, 1.1, 0.3,
  0.1, 1.9, 1.1, 0.9, 1.4, 0.3, 1.5, 0.5), nrow=5, ncol=3) 

# Run the baysout function on matrix A and store result in outliers
outliers <- baysout(A, blocks = 3, nclass=0, k = 3, num.out = 3)

# print out result
print(outliers)

# attempt to access the index
print(outliers[1,1])
```

Output is as follows:

```
print out result

print(outliers) [,1] 4 3.625798 3 2.901654 2 2.850419

attempt to access the index

print(outliers[1,1]) 4 3.625798
```

This is not the real data I am using which is much larger and I would like to gain access to the index. In the example above I would like to be able to access the number 4 on its own. It is coupled with the 3.625798 and I am not able to access each figure separately. Would anyone have any advice on how I could do this?

Comment: How about `index <- as.numeric(rownames(outliers))`? I think the documentation is not entirely correct. In any case the index is stored in the row names

Comment: Thanks you very much ekstroem. That has worked perfectly and a great answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

*solution by [ekstroem](/users/4288660)*

Use:

```
index <- as.numeric(rownames(outliers))
```

The documentation may not be entirely correct. In any case the index is stored in the row names.